# Can't commit because someone else pushed, can't pull without discarding my changes in git

Tags: xcode, git

I am working with a friend on an iOS project, and we are using git for versioning, with Xcode. My friend has committed the changes, and I have my changes locally. When I try to commit my changes, I'm getting this error in Xcode:

`hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

When I try to pull, Xcode warns me about losing my local changes:

[image]

How can we simply merge the changes? I've used TFS before, and things were more much easy, we've checked in changes, and got latest, and if there was any conflict we could solve it. We don't need branching etc, we just need to keep our code in sync.

How can I solve this "deadlock" simply as possible? Or in other words, what is analogous to "just checking in/merging/getting latest in TFS" in git? Xcode built-in solutions preferred, without terminal.

**UPDATE**:
Here is what I get if I type `git status` at the terminal.

```
Cans-MacBook-Pro:myappname Can$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   BigPostView.xib
    modified:   BigPostViewController.h
    ... (many others displayed here)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:      myappname/Storyboard.storyboard

Cans-MacBook-Pro:myappname Can$
```

Comment: I know you want Xcode specific solutions, but look into SourceTree, it is free and your situation is completely normal. I do it all the time with sourcetree.

Comment: Maybe Xcode is doing some fetching operations before effectively doing the commit? Did you try to commit from the CLI?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message you get when you try to pull ?

Comment: @aymericbeaumet I haven't and can't now.

Comment: @LeGEC I've updated the question, showing a screenshot. This is an Xcode error displayed immediately, not an error from the server.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu open up a terminal, go to your XCode directory, type `git status`, please post the output of this command (or at least enough relevant parts)

Comment: @LeGEC I've added it to the question.

Comment: @PaulCezanne I've used SourceTree and it worked perfectly. However, I still don't understand why Xcode fails at a common, simple task.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: you were stuck because of a conflict on `both modified:      myappname/Storyboard.storyboard`

Comment: @LeGEC yes, shouldn't git/xcode merge them? or at least, show a compare view so I can select the preferred version.

Answer (score 1):

You should always be able to commit your changes, since that's a local operation. You'll get an error only when you try to push your commited changes.

In order to push your commit, you'll have to pull your friend's changes first.

Comment: But I can't pull because it tells me that all my changes will be discarded.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu That's probably because you didn't commit them. You should commit them prior to the pull.

Comment: Here is what I did:

I've commited my changes. It did commit locally, but when it tried to push to remote, I've got that error in the question. When I try to pull, Xcode tells me that all my local changes will be discarded.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I've never tried to run git command via Xcode. Perhaps you should run git commands from the shell. First make sure you don't have any uncommmited changes in your branch. Then, instead of the pull you can do `git fetch`, and then `git merge origin/branch_name` to merge the remote changes to your local `branch_name` branch. Then you'll be able to push.

Comment: Maybe Xcode does something, but shouldn't such a big app like Xcode, which has native support for source control, play correctly with git?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I have no idea. You should at least run `git status` in the shell to see if you have any uncommited/unstaged work.

Comment: I've ended up using SourceTree as been suggested by @PaulCezanne